# Is there a simple method to get properties for all keys in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, dictionary

So I've created this JS code to get a map where every word in a string is the key and the amount of times that word appears is the value.

```
var txtArray = txtVar.split(" ");
var txtMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i<txtArray.length;i++){
  if(txtArray[i] in txtMap)
    txtMap[txtArray[i]] += 1;
  else
    txtMap[txtArray[i]] = 1;
}
```

Now i need to sort them so that I can somehow rank them by the 10 longest words and 10 most used words and so on and I guess I could find a way to do it by making a for loop where i stored them in  arrays and then pushed the oldest "top" word up or down the list when a new one comes along, but I think there must be a less awkward way to do this task?

Comment: `Object.keys(txtMap).sort((a, b) => txtMap[a] < txtMap[b] ? -1 : txtMap[a] > txtMap[b] ? +1 : 0)`.

Comment: Note that *in* also checks the prototype chain, so `txtMap[txtArray[i]] += 1` may have unexpected results in apparently random and difficult to find cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably an adequate approach to do as you're currently doing, then sorting/slicing those results when you're done:

```
var allWords = Object.keys(txtMap);
var tenMostFrequent = allWords
  .sort((a, b) => txtMap[b] - txtMap[a])
  .slice(0, 10);
var longestWords = allWords
  .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)
  .slice(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the words, then [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as you see fit and use [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the top 10:

```js
var txtVar = "some sample input to have something to fill the array with - random words the in are the it the what with some random whatever what what ridiculous whatever hello goodbye words the to have";

var txtArray = txtVar.split(" ");
var txtMap = {};
for (var i = 0; i<txtArray.length;i++){
  if(txtArray[i] in txtMap)
    txtMap[txtArray[i]] += 1;
  else
    txtMap[txtArray[i]] = 1;
}

var tenLongest = Object.keys(txtMap).sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  }).slice(0, 10);
console.log("Longest: ", tenLongest.join(", "));

var tenMostUsed = Object.keys(txtMap).sort(function(a, b) {
    return txtMap[b] - txtMap[a];
  }).slice(0, 10)
  .map(function(v) { return v + " (" + txtMap[v] + ")"; });
console.log("Most used: ", tenMostUsed.join(", ") );
```